# proper way to check for request method in nginx_lua

Tags: nginx, lua

I am trying to write a REST interface using nginx and lua. What I'd like to know is, what is the best way to check for the request method?  If it's a GET, I need to query a db.  If it's a POST or DELETE, I need to run another lua script to update the database. 
So far, this is what my code looks like to test what the request method is:

```
    #curl -i -X GET 'http://localhost/widgets/widget?name=testname&loc=20000' -H "Accept:application/json"
    location /widgets/widget {
            default_type "text/pain";
            #ifisEvil... unless done inside lua
            content_by_lua '
                    ngx.say("request is:",ngx.var.request_method)
                    ngx.say("the constant is:",ngx.HTTP_GET)
                    --ngx.say("the type is: ", type(ngx.HTTP_GET)

                    if ngx.var.request_method == ngx.HTTP_GET then
                            local args = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
                            for key, val in pairs(args) do
                                    if type(val) == "table" then
                                            ngx.say(key, ": ", table.concat(val, ", "))
                                    else
                                            ngx.say(key, ": ", val)
                                    end
                            end
                    end
            ';

    }
```

The output looks like this:

```
mytestdevbox2:/var/www/nsps2# curl -i -X GET 'http://localhost/widgets/widget?name=testname&loc=20000' -H "Accept:application/json"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 25 Feb 2015 13:44:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/pain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

request is:GET
the constant is:2
mytestdevbox2:/var/www/nsps2#
```

The above output explains why the if statement is failing... because I'm comparing "GET" with 2. I'd rather not make up my own list of constants if they're already available and I'm just missing something here.

I know there is an nginx variable called "$request_method" but I'd rather not use that because I want to keep all my logic in lua.  From what I've read so far, using the "if" statement in nginx is [evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)!
So I'm trying to stick to lua code for stuff like that.

Any tips on where I might have messed up my lua code?

Comment: Just compare with `'GET'` string. `If` is evil, but sometimes is still better than anything else. You have quite unnatural example. What do you really want to do?

Comment: what's unnatural about it? can you expand?  I'm all ears as i'm just new to nginx.  the code right now is just test code but having said that, checking for the request type is something quite normal no?  And then the only other logic i have is parsing the input

Comment: @AlexeyTen.  I know I can just compare it to the string GET but I guess I was wondering if there's another way, like using some existing constant, that I'm just not familiar with.

Comment: I mean, checking request method is not a goal, but a way to do something else. It would be better if you explain what's the real problem is. May be there is simpler and cleaner way to solve it.

Comment: `GET` is the constant. It the exact three bytes that you should compare with

Comment: @AlexeyTen I am writing a REST service so I need to check requests that come in to that particular uri to see if it's a GET or a POST or DELETE etc.

Comment: Well, then constants `GET`/`POST`/etc. is what you need. I really can't see any reason to write `ngx.HTTP_GET` instead of simple `'GET'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua's method constants, such as `ngx.HTTP_GET`, are according to their documentation, [mainly for `ngx.location*` calls](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#HTTP_method_constants).

So there is no "better" way of checking your method in Lua than comparing it with `GET` and the rest of the method strings.

However I would seriously consider using the ["evil" `if`](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) to split your requests based on method on nginx level.

This gives you the benefit of allowing you to configure separate logging, error handling etc. per method.